# How can I display my array values using foreach()?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to output values from my array, but they are not printing to screen in my `foreach()` loop.

This is my array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [projectId] => 2[seDate] => 2017 - 04 - 13[startTime] => 06: 57[taskToDo] => testing[studentSessionNo] =>1[studentId] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [projectId] => 4[seDate] => 2017 - 05 - 27[startTime] => 04: 53[taskToDo] => dodfddd[studentSessionNo] =>2[studentId] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [projectId] => 8[seDate] => 2017 - 05 - 17[startTime] => 01: 01[taskToDo] => rrrrrrr[studentSessionNo] => 5[studentId] => 1
        )
)
```

This is my code:

```
<div>
    <?php
    foreach($info as $info){
          echo "<label>Session Date : ".$value['seDate']."</label>";
          echo "<label>Start Time : ".$value['startTime']."</label>";
          echo "<label>End Time : ".$value['taskToDo']."</label>";
          echo "<label>Task To Do  : ".$value['studentSessionNo']."</label><br />";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `$value` to `$info` then read up on [foreach loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: @JohnConde this is working my friend. thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($info as $value){
    ........
    .......
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question that could have been easily answered with a quick trip to the PHP Manual. That said, for a question to be deemed resolved on SO, an answer must be posted and then accepted.  John Conde knows this but occasionally answers questions via comments -- this leads to questions appearing unresolved/abandoned on SO.  I'll provide some input-relevant explanation to help you understand `foreach()` and how it relates to your multi-dimensional array.

[foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) requires the first value to be the input array's variable name.

Depending on what parts of your array you wish to handle inside your loop, you have two choices about what comes after the `as`.

1. If you want to only work with the values in your array, then you declare a variable name to represent each element value in the array.
2. If you want to access both the keys and the values, then you must declare a variable name for the keys, then `=>`, then a variable name for the values.

This is a php declaration of your array:

```
$array=array(
    0=>array("projectId"=>2,"seDate"=>"2017 - 04 - 13","startTime"=>"06: 57","taskToDo"=>"testing","studentSessionNo"=>1,"studentId"=>1),
    1=>array("projectId"=>4,"seDate"=>"2017 - 05 - 27","startTime"=>"04: 53","taskToDo"=>"dodfddd","studentSessionNo"=>2,"studentId"=>1),
    2=>array("projectId"=>8,"seDate"=>"2017 - 05 - 17","startTime"=>"01: 01","taskToDo"=>"rrrrrrr","studentSessionNo"=>5,"studentId"=>1)
);
```

If you want to iterate through each level of your multi-dimensional array, then you can do so with a foreach loop nested inside of a foreach loop:

```
foreach($array as $index=>$subarray){
    echo "For subarray number $index<br>";
    foreach($subarray as $key=>$value){
        echo "$key has value value<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The output will be:

```
For subarray number 0
projectId has value 2
seDate has value 2017 - 04 - 13
startTime has value 06: 57
taskToDo has value testing
studentSessionNo has value 1
studentId has value 1

For subarray number 1
projectId has value 4
seDate has value 2017 - 05 - 27
startTime has value 04: 53
taskToDo has value dodfddd
studentSessionNo has value 2
studentId has value 1

For subarray number 2
projectId has value 8
seDate has value 2017 - 05 - 17
startTime has value 01: 01
taskToDo has value rrrrrrr
studentSessionNo has value 5
studentId has value 1
```

You will notice that I didn't echo `$subarray` because arrays cannot be echoed.  If you want to display the contents of each subarray, you can use just one foreach loop with [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), or [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) like this:

```
foreach($array as $index=>$subarray){
    var_export($subarray);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  'projectId' => 2,
  'seDate' => '2017 - 04 - 13',
  'startTime' => '06: 57',
  'taskToDo' => 'testing',
  'studentSessionNo' => 1,
  'studentId' => 1,
)
array (
  'projectId' => 4,
  'seDate' => '2017 - 05 - 27',
  'startTime' => '04: 53',
  'taskToDo' => 'dodfddd',
  'studentSessionNo' => 2,
  'studentId' => 1,
)
array (
  'projectId' => 8,
  'seDate' => '2017 - 05 - 17',
  'startTime' => '01: 01',
  'taskToDo' => 'rrrrrrr',
  'studentSessionNo' => 5,
  'studentId' => 1,
)
```

Finally, and specifically for your question, the simple fix to get your output working is to change the variable name after `as` to `$value`.  This will allow you to access the subarray's values as intended.

```
<div>
    <?php
    foreach($info as $value){
        echo "<label>Session Date : ".$value['seDate']."</label>";
        echo "<label>Start Time : ".$value['startTime']."</label>";
        echo "<label>End Time : ".$value['taskToDo']."</label>";
        echo "<label>Task To Do  : ".$value['studentSessionNo']."</label><br />";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```